# How to vertically merge two images?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

How can I vertically merge two images using Python and PIL library? I tried doing this:

```
images_list = ['pil_text.png','pic.jpeg']
imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in images_list ]
min_img_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]

img_merge = np.vstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_img_shape,Image.ANTIALIAS) ) for i in imgs ) )
img_merge = Image.fromarray( img_merge)
img_merge.save( 'terracegarden_v.jpg' )
```

But my image on the bottom is squished.

Comment: Well, you explicitly resize all images to be the same size as the smallest image in your set, without respecting aspect ratio. What's the desired behavior? Do you want them to have the same width only with arbitrary heights or ...?

Comment: You likely resized one of your images (given they are not the same size). Why *wouldn't* they be squished?

Comment: Yes I do yeputons how could I make the widths the same but make the height so that it respect the ratio to avoid the picture looking squished

Answer (score 7):

Note that unless you want to for reasons to do with a larger script, you don't need to involve numpy in this process.

```
from PIL import Image
images_list = ['pil_text.png', 'pic.jpeg']
imgs = [Image.open(i) for i in images_list]

# If you're using an older version of Pillow, you might have to use .size[0] instead of .width
# and later on, .size[1] instead of .height
min_img_width = min(i.width for i in imgs)

total_height = 0
for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    # If the image is larger than the minimum width, resize it
    if img.width > min_img_width:
        imgs[i] = img.resize((min_img_width, int(img.height / img.width * min_img_width)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    total_height += imgs[i].height

# I have picked the mode of the first image to be generic. You may have other ideas
# Now that we know the total height of all of the resized images, we know the height of our final image
img_merge = Image.new(imgs[0].mode, (min_img_width, total_height))
y = 0
for img in imgs:
    img_merge.paste(img, (0, y))

    y += img.height
img_merge.save('terracegarden_v.jpg')
```